# SPSS Sum the data that meets particular condition (numerical variable)

Tags: spss

I am trying to sum the income of the particular members that shares the same "index" number and present it as a new variable HHincome.

For example:
[Members with index value of 1 would be summed and presented as a new variable HHincome = 26+31+9+7.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vQ0q.png)

The index number exist from 1 to 466 and there are total of 2504 members.

The followings are the commands that i tried to implement but it doesn't seem to work.

```
compute HHincome = 0.
execute.

vector vindex = index1 TO index466.
vector vincome = income1 TO income2504.
    LOOP #vecid = 1 TO 466.
    do IF (vindex(#vecid) eq 1 and not missing (vincome(#vecid))).
    COMPUTE HHincome = HHincome+vincome(#vecid).
    end if.
    End LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

---

This is my other attempt

```
LOOP j = 1 to 466.
    compute HHincome = 0.
        Loop i = 1 to 2504.
            do if (data[i, index] eq j).
            compute HHincome = HHincome + data[i,income].
            end if.
        End loop.
End loop.
Execute.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SPSS you don't need to loop over rows (`vector` and `loop` are for looping over columns). What you need instead is the `aggregate` function. Like this:

```
aggregate outfile=* mode=addvariables /break=index /HHincome=sum(income).
```